# Wordpress admin-ajax.php not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am using a custom options framework which is working in all browsers except for Internet Explorer (what a surprise!). The submit form is configured like this;

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() .'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; ?>" method="post" id="mobeus-form">
```

In all other browsers, when the form is submitted, the changes are saved as expected. But, in Internet Explorer, it seems to be accessing the PHP file directly, as it has this in the url bar;

```
http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

The page itself has a line of text;

```
{"error":false,"message":"Settings Successfully Saved!","type":""}
```

Nothing else happens, the settings are not saved, and I am left baffled. If anyone could help I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

admin-ajax.php file is meant for ajax process, so instead of trying it in form action attribute try with jquery stuff to pass the data to admin-ajax and retrieve the value, or try something like below to use the same form with jquery submission.

```
var data = jQuery("#myForm :input").serializeArray();
jQuery.post(jQuery("#myForm").attr("action"),data, function(info) {
       // success code ;
});
```